# Google Script check a column if contains a certain word

Tags: function, gmail, google-sheets

I am new to Google Scripting.

I created a script where Google Spreadsheet should connect to GMail. Everything is working well.

My problem is, I need to check if an email content has the word "ORDER". If yes, it should get the word "ORDER" and the numbers after it.

For example, an email contains "ORDER 90104" in the message body, then the Google script should insert ORDER 90104 to a column in the sheet. An example email could be:

> *Hi, the customer is requesting for **ORDER 90104**. Thanks.*

Is this even possible? As of now, I used [getPlainBody()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getPlainBody%28%29) and I can get all the contents of the email and put it in a column. My plan was to check that column and look for the word ORDER. Though I can't find/end with a solution for it.

Here's my working code getting the email content of the 1st three emails:

```
function getGMail() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,3);
cell = sheet.getRange("A1");

for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    threadMessage = threads[i].getMessages();
    var emailContent = threadMessage[0].getPlainBody();
    cell.offset(i,0).setValue(emailContent);    
}
```

}

Any advice or comments will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello theladydevbugger,

As you didn't gave a lot of code my answer will be quite short: yes you can do that!
How: use a regexp: `/ORDER [0-9]+/g.`
How to use the regexp: bellow a sample code

```
var emailBody = yourMail.getPlainBody(); // supposing "yourMail" is the mail you retrieved
var isThereAnyOrder = false;
if(mailBody.search(/ORDER [0-9]+/g)>-1){
  isThereAnyOrder=true;
  var order=mailBody.match(/ORDER [0-9]+/g)>-1)[0];
  Logger.log(order);
  // do something with the order
  }
 else{
   // there is no order do nothing
 }
```

Comment: OMG thank you so much, Harold! I'll give this a try. :) I'll update you if I had it working.

Comment: Hi Harold, I pasted my working code on my question and tried your answer. Replaced some variables etc. But I'm getting an error here: var order=mailBody.match(/ORDER [0-9]+/g)>-1)[0]; It says Missing ";". I checked your code and it doesnt seem to lack any ;. Any ideas? Thank you. :)

Comment: my bad... var order=mailBody.match(/ORDER [0-9]+/g)[0]; will work better (I had copied paste the above line without re reading it...). the ">-1)" had nothing to do there. [sorry]

Comment: It worked! I have no knowledge yet with RegExp but because of this, I'll study it now. Thank you so much, Harold! Thaaaanks! :)

Comment: RegExp are quite painfull to me, but I use two sites to build and test them:http://www.jslab.dk/tools.regex.php and http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: Thank you so much Harold, for the links above and for helping me too. :)